# How exactly does backend work from a developer perspective?

Tags: server, webserver, backend

Theres a ton of videos and websites trying to explain backend vs frontend, but unfortunately none of them explains it in a way that you know how to develop a backend - driven website (at least I haven't found anything good).

So, I wanted to ensure that I understood it and kindly ask you to confirm or correct me on this topic.

#### Example:

I wanted to build Mini - Google. I have a Database containing 1000 stored websites.

---

**Assumption #1:**
Everytime I type something into the search bar, the autofill suggestions change. This means, everytime i type, another website / API gets called returning the current autofill suggestions. On a developer site, this means the website e.g. is a Python script which gets called with the current word typed in as a Parameter and is returning all suggestions as e.g. JSON:

```
// Client Side Script
function ontype(input):
    suggestions = get("https://api.googlemini.com/suggestions?q=" + str(input))
    show(suggestions)
```

---

**Assumption #2:**
This also means I could manually call the website containing the Python script, providing a random word and it would always return a JSON containing the autofill suggestions for that word.

---

**Question #1:**
If `A#1` turns out `true` but `A#2` turns out `false`, how could I prevent a user from randomly accessing the "API" while still returning results when called by a script?

---

**Assumption #3:**
After pressing enter, my website googlemini.com/search?... would be called. As google.com/search reloads everytime searching for a new query (or going to page 2 etc.), I assume, instead of calling an API, when the server gets the client request, it first searches through its database, sorts the results and then returns a whole html as a static webpage:

```
// Server Side Script
@app.route("/search")
function oncall():
    query = getparam("q")
    results = searchdatabase(query)
    html = buildhtml(results)
    return html
```

---

**Question #2:**
Often, I hear (or at least understand it this way) that database and webserver are 2 seperate servers. How would that work? Wouldn't that mean the database server needs to be accessible to the web too (of course it would have security layers etc., but technically it would)? How could I access the database server from the webserver?

---

**Question #3:**
Are there, on a technical basis, any other ways to build backend services?

---

That's it. I would also appreciate any recommendations like videos, websites or others to learn how to technically setup and / or secure backend servers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question you can yes there is a way to prevent miss use.
What you can do is add identifier to api like Auth token to identify a user and every time a user access the api you can save the count on the server n whenever the count has exceeded a limit within a time span you can reject the call. And the limit can be set in such a way that it doesn't trouble the honest user and punishes the wrong one. There  are even more complex and effective methods but this is the basic idea.

For question number to let me explain you a simple concept a database is a very efficient, resourcefull and expensive data storage solution we never want it to be used in a general sense as varible store or something. We always want to access the database in call get the data process the data update the data. So we do it data way and its not necessary you make sepreate server for data base. The thing is we mostly make databse to be accessible to various platforms android, ios, windows. So its better to add some abstraction and keep data base as a separte entity.

For the last, I am not well aware about what you meant by other but I am listing some backend teechnologies, some of these might be used in isolation some of these not some other tools as well.

- Django
- FLask
- Djnago rest
- GraphQL
- SQL
- PHP
- Node
- Deno